# How can I filter the files found in FSO.GetFolder to only show certain file types?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the macro below to create a popup and open the newest file in a folder, however I want to only search for .xlsm files in the folder so it will open the newest .xlsm file in TestFolder.  Is there a way to do this or have it search for files names that only begin with "TestFile*"

```
Sub Practice()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim fol As Object
Dim fil As Object
Dim temp As Date

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = FSO.GetFolder("C:TestFolder")

Dim newest As Date
Dim newestFile As String
For Each fil In fol.Files
    temp = fil.DateLastModified
    If (newest = #12:00:00 AM#) Or (temp > newest) Then
        newest = temp
        newestFile = fil.Path
    End If
Next fil
MsgBox "Newest File: " & newestFile & " (" & newest & ")"
Workbooks.Open newestFile
End Sub
```

Comment: FSO has GetExtensionName or you can use `If fil.Name Like “*.xlsm”`

Answer (score 0):

- Add `If` clause to validate file name with "TestFile*.xlsm"
- Add `If` clause to check if the file is found, otherwise `Open` raises error.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Practice()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim fsoFolder As Object
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    Dim dTemp As Date
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fsoFolder = FSO.GetFolder("d:\Temp\data") ' Modify as needed
    Dim Newest As Date
    Dim NewestFile As String
    Newest = #1/1/1904#
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        ' Check file name
        If fsoFile.Name Like "TestFile*.xlsm" Then
            dTemp = fsoFile.DateLastModified
            If dTemp > Newest Then
                Newest = dTemp
                NewestFile = fsoFile.Path
            End If
        End If
    Next fsoFile
    If dTemp = #12:00:00 AM# Then
        MsgBox "Can't find files"
    Else
        MsgBox "Newest File: " & NewestFile & " (" & Newest & ")"
        Workbooks.Open NewestFile
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Open Latest File

**Usage (Example)**

```
Sub OpenLatestFileTEST()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const FileExtension As String = "xlsm"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = OpenLatestFile(FolderPath, FileExtension)
    ' i.e.:
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = OpenLatestFile("C:\Test", "xlsm")
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' the function showed a message
    
    ' Continue using 'wb', e.g.:
    
    MsgBox "Opened file """ & wb.Name & """.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function OpenLatestFile( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    ByVal FileExtension As String) _
As Workbook
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Open Latest File"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The folder """ & FolderPath & """ doesn't exist!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim fFile As Object, fDate As Date, nPath As String, nDate As Date
    
    For Each fFile In fso.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files
        If StrComp(fso.GetExtensionName(fFile.Name), FileExtension, _
                vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            fDate = fFile.DateLastModified
            If fDate > nDate Then
                nDate = fDate
                nPath = fFile.Path
            End If
        End If
    Next fFile
    
    If Len(nPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No ""." & FileExtension & """ files found!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set OpenLatestFile = Workbooks.Open(nPath)

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```